# Number.EPSILON and Number.MIN_VALUE. Why are two different?

Tags: javascript

`Number.EPSILON` The smallest interval between two representable numbers.

`Number.MIN_VALUE`
    The smallest positive representable number - that is, the positive number closest to zero (without actually being zero).

`Min_Value` is the smallest positive number that can be represented.

`Epsilon` is the minimum interval between two representable numbers.

**Why is Epsilon the not closest to zero?**

`Number.EPSILON === Number.MIN_VALUE false`

`Number.EPSILON 2.220446049250313e-16`

`Number.MIN_VALUE 5e-324`

Comment: Not sure what your questions is, doesn't the descriptions you have copy pasted tell you what you need to know.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of Number.EPSILON is [slightly different than that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON) :

> The `Number.EPSILON` property represents the difference between 1 and the smallest floating point number greater than 1.

The difference here is `representable` vs `difference` (measurable)

In Javascript, numbers are stored in the [IEEE 754 Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), meaning we can represent very small and large values, but only "approximately". For very big numbers, the addition or subtraction operation will not be exact, since the representation is not exact. It's the same if we want to add or substract very "little" numbers. `Number.EPSILON` can be used to compare floating numbers, so we cannot use an "approximative" representation for that.